# "Unverified org Wide Email Address" Error on Workflow in sandbox even if email is verified

Tags: workflow, salesforcedx, org-wide-email

We have a org wide email addressed which has been "Verified" into our sandbox.
I understant org wide email addressed is unsupported metadata, so this was achieved as pre deployment step.

Into our repo, we have a workflow that send email alert to that org wide email address. "

**Workflow**

```
...
<senderAddress>noreply@mycompany.com.au</senderAddress>
<senderType>OrgWideEmailAddress</senderType>
```

The problem we are facing is that we are still getting the following error even if this org wide email address is verified:

> You must specify a verified Org Wide Email Address for this sender
>   type.

Is that a bug in the metadata api or expected behaviour ? Ideally we would like to not have to do that as a post deployment step.

PS: We are running DX under api version 43.0