# “Unverified org Wide Email Address” Error on Workflow even if email is verified

Tags: workflow, salesforcedx, org-wide-email

We have a org wide email addressed which has been "Verified" into our sandbox. I understant org wide email addressed is unsupported metadata, so this was achieved as pre deployment step.

Into our repo, we have a workflow that send email alert to that org wide email address. "

Workflow

...
noreply@mycompany.com.au
OrgWideEmailAddress
The problem we are facing is that we are still getting the following error even if this org wide email address is verified:

## You must specify a verified Org Wide Email Address for this sender type.

Is that a bug in the metadata api or expected behaviour ? Ideally we would like to not have to do that as a post deployment step.

PS: We are running DX under api version 44.0

This question was asked [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/228276/unverified-org-wide-email-address-error-on-workflow-even-if-email-is-verified/237974#237974) but no answer was left

Comment: We should close this, ideally. Adding a new question where another isn't answered will eventually only lead to confusion. I tried voting to close as duplicate, but the search to find the duplicate doesn't seem to work for me when the two questions have the exact same titles.